# Renaming a single value with multiple instances/occurrences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DF of mulitple NFL players, for this example I will be using stats based off of the 2022 year, which I have already transformed to a semi presentable state. When reviewing the Data, I noticed that quite a few players had 2TM and even 3TM as their defined 'Tm' column value. I am trying to change those values into the team that they ended the year with for simplicity and consistency.

The desired result would be to only rename Christian McCaffrey's value of '2TM' in the 'Tm' column to 'SFO' while not changing other values further down.

For reference I'll just be showing the first 10 rows of the DF where one instance of this problem occurs.

```
Player  Tm  Age Att Yds TD  Y/A Y/G Fmb Age_Rank    Att_Rank    Yds_Rank    TD_Rank Y/A_Rank    Y/G_Rank    Fmb_Rank
1   Derrick Henry   TEN 28.0    349.0   1538.0  13.0    4.4 96.1    6.0 0.90    1.00    0.98    0.97    0.41    0.98    1.00
2   Josh Jacobs LVR 24.0    340.0   1653.0  12.0    4.9 97.2    3.0 0.37    0.98    1.00    0.92    0.69    1.00    0.75
3   Nick Chubb  CLE 27.0    302.0   1525.0  12.0    5.0 89.7    1.0 0.76    0.96    0.96    0.92    0.80    0.96    0.36
4   Saquon Barkley  NYG 25.0    295.0   1312.0  10.0    4.4 82.0    1.0 0.52    0.94    0.94    0.86    0.41    0.94    0.36
5   Najee Harris    PIT 24.0    272.0   1034.0  7.0 3.8 60.8    3.0 0.37    0.92    0.74    0.69    0.12    0.62    0.75
6   Dalvin Cook MIN 27.0    264.0   1173.0  8.0 4.4 69.0    4.0 0.76    0.90    0.90    0.78    0.41    0.84    0.88
7   Jamaal Williams DET 27.0    262.0   1066.0  17.0    4.1 62.7    3.0 0.76    0.88    0.82    1.00    0.27    0.66    0.75
8   Miles Sanders   PHI 25.0    259.0   1269.0  11.0    4.9 74.6    2.0 0.52    0.86    0.92    0.88    0.69    0.90    0.60
9   Christian McCaffrey 2TM 26.0    244.0   1139.0  8.0 4.7 67.0    1.0 0.62    0.84    0.88    0.78    0.58    0.82    0.36
10  Ezekiel Elliott DAL 27.0    231.0   876.0   12.0    3.8 58.4    0.0 0.76    0.82    0.60    0.92    0.12    0.54    0.10
```

I tried to reference a single index and replace the value with the new value, and not rename all instances of '2TM' with .iloc but it ends up changing all the values to NaN except fot the 'Tm' value which is now correct.

```
print(data_radar_filtered.iloc[8])

Player      Christian McCaffrey
Tm                          2TM
Age                        26.0
Att                       244.0
Yds                      1139.0
TD                          8.0
Y/A                         4.7
Y/G                        67.0
Fmb                         1.0
Age_Rank                   0.62
Att_Rank                   0.84
Yds_Rank                   0.88
TD_Rank                    0.78
Y/A_Rank                   0.58
Y/G_Rank                   0.82
Fmb_Rank                   0.36
Name: 8, dtype: object

data_radar_filtered.iloc[8] = data_radar_filtered.iloc[8].str.replace('2TM', 'SFO', regex=False)
print(data_radar_filtered.iloc[8])
print(data_radar_filtered.head(10))
Player      Christian McCaffrey
Tm                          SFO
Age                         NaN
Att                         NaN
Yds                         NaN
TD                          NaN
Y/A                         NaN
Y/G                         NaN
Fmb                         NaN
Age_Rank                    NaN
Att_Rank                    NaN
Yds_Rank                    NaN
TD_Rank                     NaN
Y/A_Rank                    NaN
Y/G_Rank                    NaN
Fmb_Rank                    NaN
Name: 8, dtype: object
                Player   Tm   Age    Att     Yds    TD  Y/A   Y/G  Fmb  \
0        Derrick Henry  TEN  28.0  349.0  1538.0  13.0  4.4  96.1  6.0   
1          Josh Jacobs  LVR  24.0  340.0  1653.0  12.0  4.9  97.2  3.0   
2           Nick Chubb  CLE  27.0  302.0  1525.0  12.0  5.0  89.7  1.0   
3       Saquon Barkley  NYG  25.0  295.0  1312.0  10.0  4.4  82.0  1.0   
4         Najee Harris  PIT  24.0  272.0  1034.0   7.0  3.8  60.8  3.0   
5          Dalvin Cook  MIN  27.0  264.0  1173.0   8.0  4.4  69.0  4.0   
6      Jamaal Williams  DET  27.0  262.0  1066.0  17.0  4.1  62.7  3.0   
7        Miles Sanders  PHI  25.0  259.0  1269.0  11.0  4.9  74.6  2.0   
8  Christian McCaffrey  SFO   NaN    NaN     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN   
9      Ezekiel Elliott  DAL  27.0  231.0   876.0  12.0  3.8  58.4  0.0   

   Age_Rank  Att_Rank  Yds_Rank  TD_Rank  Y/A_Rank  Y/G_Rank  Fmb_Rank  
0      0.90      1.00      0.98     0.97      0.41      0.98      1.00  
1      0.37      0.98      1.00     0.92      0.69      1.00      0.75  
2      0.76      0.96      0.96     0.92      0.80      0.96      0.36  
3      0.52      0.94      0.94     0.86      0.41      0.94      0.36  
4      0.37      0.92      0.74     0.69      0.12      0.62      0.75  
5      0.76      0.90      0.90     0.78      0.41      0.84      0.88  
6      0.76      0.88      0.82     1.00      0.27      0.66      0.75  
7      0.52      0.86      0.92     0.88      0.69      0.90      0.60  
8       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  
9      0.76      0.82      0.60     0.92      0.12      0.54      0.10
```

I thought about making a dictionary with the column names corresponding to the correct values, but I'm not quite sure how to implement that.

Comment: Sorry for wonky formatting, not sure how to import Jupyter notebook into stack overflow well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Dataframe.loc[]` method:

```
# DataFrame.loc[row_index,col_indexe] = value

data_radar_filtered.loc[8, 'Tm'] = "SFO"
```

or you may try `DataFrame.at[]`:

```
# DataFrame.at[row_index,col_indexer] = value

data_radar_filtered.at[8, 'Tm'] = "SFO"
```